# Save list of integers(1 and 0) to byte and write the number to file

Tags: c#, byte

I have a list of integers `var listOfBits = new List<int>();`it consists of integers (1000 1100 0000 1110 0100 ...). These bits represent a number in binary. Now I need write the number to a file. But I am kinda stuck. This is what I was thinking:

```
void writeFile(List<int> listOfBits)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfBits.Count; i += 8)
            {
                byte exitByte= 0;
                for(int j=0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    if (listOfBits[i + j] == 1)
                    {
                        //some kind of right shift maybe?
                    }
                }
                  //write exitByte to file...

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a left-shift:

```
exitByte = (exitByte << 1) + 1;
```

and if the value is `0` then

```
exitByte = exitByte << 1;
```

Note that this assumes that the most significant bits come first. If this is not the case, reverse the inner loop but still use left-shift.

Since you have to shift in both cases (1 and 0), it is easier like this:

```
exitByte <<= 1; // Shift left by 1 position, i.e., multiply by 2.
if (listOfBits[i + j] == 1)
{
    exitByte++; // Add one.
}
```